# How to fix peak/pinch in one vertex (after subdivision)

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am very new to 3D work, but I have hit a snag in my learning.

I have been researching (google and forum searches) about how to fix this "peak" or "pinch" issue. I thought it was double vertices, but that only fixed the issue on a couple. I have dissolved the vertex and then added the edge back in, which works, but shifts the peak/pinch to another vertex. I have not learned to make curves, so I am guessing that maybe I should do that instead of using planes, extruding, and moving everything.

Could someone offer a recommendation? 
Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Suggest start here: https://topologyguides.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and report back:

- Verify no duplicate verts
- Verify Normals Outside & In
- Verify Normals are not bugged by doing the *Set From Faces* Normals (use <kbd>F3</kbd> to search)
- Checked for Clear Edge (Sharp Edge)
- Try smoothing Object
- Loop cut and added additional loop for potential topology issue...

And as a final check, adjust your Auto Smooth Angle...

Edit I'm adding another check on the list. Sometimes Recalculating normals is not enough and you need to force all normals to be perpendicular (yes they will visually look fine)

*Set From Faces* in the *Shading* tab of the *Tool Shelf*.

What's happened is your normals have got bent out of shape in a weird way that the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> make normals consistent doesn't see as a problem.

Comment: Normals! Thanks a lot. That fixed my issues.